# How to select from a range of partitions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I hope you can help me!

I have a number of partitions in my database for the last few years. Their naming convention is pYYYYMM. For example p202206 would be for June 2022.

How would I go about saying: SELECT * FROM TABLE where partitions are within last 6 months?

The below works - does this seem more efficient than having date ranges in the where statement as you are explictly specifying the partitions to search?

```
    WITH t1 as (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(PARTITION_NAME) FROM information_schema.PARTITIONS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ran' AND TABLE_NAME = 'order_data' and PARTITION_DESCRIPTION > 2016)
SELECT * INTO @items FROM t1;
WITH t2 as (select concat('select * from order_data PARTITION(',@items,')'))
SELECT * INTO @query FROM t2;
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the date range in the WHERE clause.

You can confirm it will do partition pruning with EXPLAIN PARTITIONS (I think recent versions of MySQL include the partition info by default in EXPLAIN output).

If partition pruning works, it is practically the same in performance as specifying the partitions.

You should only specify partitions if your query conditions *don't* allow partition pruning to work automatically.

Comment: Thanks. So if I partition based on YEAR_MONTH(date) then will querying WHERE date > xxxx, will it work? Because the partition isn't actually in a standard field, it's derived

Comment: The functions that you can use in partitioning that are optimized for partition pruning are: YEAR(), TO_DAYS(), TO_SECONDS() (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html)

Comment: I get that, but surely it still works as I have proposed? What's the drawback of year month? Is it slower to actually organise data into partitions? Or you can't just use a where statement and need to specify the actual partition?

Comment: It returns the right result, but it won't use partition pruning. That is, it will scan every partition, even though some of the partitions cannot contain any rows that match that condition. The way partition pruning is implemented, it only checks for certain expressions and functions. Otherwise it falls back to scanning every partition.

Comment: Even if I have specifically specified the partitions to check, as in my query? That seems a bit strange? I'd understand if it was in a where condition  but if I tell it to search partition 1, 2 and 3  why would it scan the others?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the partitions, and that takes priority over automatic partition pruning. I was describing the automatic partition pruning that is done by the optimizer.

Comment: Aha okay, sorry. I'm not very experienced with MySQL so I really appreciate all the help